# How to solve the question below?

Tags: combinatorics

Please give me hints on how to solve the following problem:

> A class has $100$ students. Let $a_i, 1 \le i \le 100$, denote the number of friends the $i$-th student has in the class. For each $0 \le j \le 99$, let $c_j$ denote the number of students having *at least* $j$ friends. Show that
>
> $$\sum _{i = 1} ^{100} a_i = \sum _{i = 0} ^{99} c_i .$$

I could solve the problem as follows but could not write a mathematical proof.

Let l = thing on left side

0 <=L <=9900

If R = Thing of right side

0 <=R <=9900

Hence L=R

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**: Consider student $i$, who has $a_i$ friends. He contributes value $a_i$ to the left-hand side. On the other hand, he is a student who have at least $1$ friend, and at least $2$ friends, ..., and at least $a_i$ friends. So he contributes $1$ to each of the terms $c_1,c_2,\dots,c_{a_i}$.